# What does this ~/ mean on command line

Tags: windows, shell, unix, batch-file, mule

I had to install mule license and this is the command required to run from bin directory.

```
mule -installLicense ~/license.lic
```

When I run this command, it says can't find file `license.lic`. Where is the license file supposed to be to run as it states in command.

I was able to run after removing `~/` though but would like to understand what does this mean

Comment: Assuming this is in the context of a shell/bash script then [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Tilde-Expansion) is the relevant section of the bash manual. Windows has similar expansions but I believe they all start with `%`.

Comment: `~` is expanded by the shell to the user's home directory, same as `$HOME`

Comment: Thanks for the link @EtanReisner I'll accept the answer if you move your comment to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *nix systems, `~` always refers to the current user's home directory.  So, if you ran `mule -installLicense ~/license.lic` and it didn't work, it means that you had the file stored somewhere else.